# Proportion of papers involving grad students and postdoc

Tags: publications

I am wondering if there are studies measuring the proportion of research papers involving at least one graduate student (master, PhD) or Postdocs in the authors.

Comment: This must vary enormously by field/sub-field/sub-sub-field etc. Do you have a specific subject area in mind?

Comment: I agree with @astronat. In biology this would be very close to 100%. In CS I'd guess it was smaller, in math smaller still, and in humanities probably quite a small %.

Comment: This was wide on purpose, I have a feeling that across subjects the percentage is extremly high. Around my network (math/cs) it seems to be above 95%.